# How to set custom invoice number

Tags: magento2, sequence, sales-invoice

What I would like to achieve is to have the invoice number defined as so:

```
 YYYYMMDDD
```

Where **`YYYY`** represents the current year, **`MM`** the current month and **`DDD`** the number that increments for each invoice.

The issue is that I don't know how to automatically reset the three digits at the beginning of each month.

```
Example:

1st invoice of March: 202003001

2nd invoice of March: 202003002

3rd invoice of March: 202003003

1st invoice of April: 202004001
```

Comment: you refer this link :- https://github.com/mage2pro/sales-sequence

Comment: @MohitPatel hi, unfortunately this plugin doesn't seem to achieve what I want. I can already modify the prefix as I wish and change the length of digits. What I want is to reset the `auto_increment` at the beginning of each month.